# Streaming MP3 (using SWF) over SSL works in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE 7 or 8

Tags: php, flash, internet-explorer, ssl, http-headers

I'm using [WP Audio player](http://wpaudioplayer.com/) to steam mp3 files.

This is how I embed the player:

```
            AudioPlayer.embed("player_new_7b4c6a94c8f3cc3f79ce7b8cc4946103", {  
                soundFile: "file/read/Mdjk7EGOzSzNUmNa8NYhgn6oCQwxoKhzw27EL27cgwCUUd9BLYpRIkt",  
                noinfo: "yes",
                autostart: "no" ,
                animation: "no",
                buffer: 1,
                remaining: "yes"
            });
```

PHP gets the file and then outputs the contents:

```
$file = new File();
if($data = $file->readFromInbox($request->get('file'))
{
    header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");    
    header('Content-Length: ' . $data->getSize());
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');     
    header("Cache-Control: no-store");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0,must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
    echo $data->getData();
    exit();
}
else
{
  $this->redirect404();
}
```

The whole application is using SSL. There is no standard HTTP port 80 access.

This works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Opera etc. but not for IE.

I read this post: http://faindu.wordpress.com/2008/04/18/ie7-ssl-xml-flex-error-2032-stream-error/

Apparently flash has problems opening files over SSL when using IE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

EDIT: This works in IE9. Just not IE7 or IE8

Comment: Why not using non SSL streaming then?

Comment: Hey @Quamis, because the whole application runs over SSL. If i'm on an SSL page and I stream through http instead of https, IE will throw an error telling me that I'm requesting an SSL page where some components on the page aren't encrypted...

Comment: if you point the swf file to directly download the file instead of streaming it through PHP is there any difference? I've seen cases where the headers sent by apache made some things work, and had to mirror those php-side afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

These headers is what solved the problem:

```
header ("Cache-Control: no-store");
header ("Expires: -1");
header ("Pragma: public");
```

Plus, of course, with the standard headers:

```
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");    
header('Content-Length: ' . $data->getSize());
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
```